# Executing a file that is in a buffer

Tags: python, windows, memory, executable, portable-executable

I have an executable file in a buffer and I want to execute it without writing it to a file.  Is this possible?  Sample of my code:

```
with open("somefile.exe", "rb") as exe_file:
    executable_string = exe_file.read()
    run(executable_string)
def run(executable_string):
    <code to make it run>
```

Comment: I dont think this is actually possible through python...maybe make a tempfile?

Comment: This would require using ctypes or a custom extension module to call undocumented system services such as `NtCreateProcess` , `NtCreateThread`, `NtQueryInformationProcess`, `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`, `NtWriteVirtualMemory`, and `NtDuplicateObject` in order to create the process and thread and set up the process parameters and stack. I can't imagine why you'd go through all of that instead of simply creating a temporary file. Note that the file can specify `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` to have the cache manager avoid writing data to disk as long as sufficient memory is available.

Comment: On Windows you could create a [Python RAM disk](http://www.eterlogic.com/help/vdsdk/PythonPage.html) and copy the file to it. There appear to be similar modules for other OSs.

Comment: @martineau, [Eterlogic Virtual Drive SDK](http://www.eterlogic.com/help/vdsdk/ApiPage.html) -- this requires a kernel driver and a registered COM interface.

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, but there's a free version for non-commercial use.

Comment: @martineau, so to keep from writing a temporary file to disk (and probably not even if `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` is used), you're going to install a kernel driver and COM interface in the registry (requires Administrator privileges and a whole lot of disk access) and go through all of the work to create and use a RAM disk. I don't get it.

Comment: @eryksun: In order to execute an arbitrary executable, the OS must be able to read it off a storage device — and setting up such a memory-back device in Windows is fairly involved AFAIK. At least with my suggestion it all gets done through documented (and supported) system interfaces as opposed to calling a bunch of undocumented system services as you suggested. It also unclear why the OP wants to copy something already that's in an executable file into memory then execute from there that as opposed to just letting the OS read the file into memory and execute it as it does normally.

Comment: @martineau My pseudo code wasn't very helpful for explaining my motives, sorry.  I want to be able to do this because I'm receiving the executable as a base64 encoded string from a separate process and I was wondering if there was an easy way to handle it after decoding it without writing it to the disk on a file that was going to get deleted anyways.  Tempfile seems like it's the solution to my problem. Thanks to all for responding.

Comment: @martineau, I didn't suggest using the undocumented interfaces. I just said that's what you'd have to use to build an arbitrary process in memory without using the normal route of mapping a file as an image section. I assumed the executable wasn't in a file on disk, or that maybe it was decrypted in memory. BTW, the corresponding os flag for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` is `os.O_SHORT_LIVED`. Unfortunately the tempfile module doesn't use this flag, so you'd have to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obfuscate an executable that you are transporting over the web and you don't want it to hit disk, the better solution would be to ship it as a DLL.  Create a process like notepad.exe or Calc.exe with the SW_HIDE parameter (using ShellExecute or CreateProcess) then inject your DLL using Manual Mapping, which doesn't require a file on disk and then execute your main function.